# Should the arraylist passed to an ArrayAdapter of a List be thread-safe?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

The array list we pass to a custom array adapter are we supposed to modify it in a thread safe way?
I mean if I have   `private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomObject>` and I  instantiate it with my `ArrayList` of `CustomObject`s if I later want to modify that array list or objects in the array list in order to then notify the adapter that the UI should be updated should I do it in a thread safe way? E.g. passing a synchronized array list?

Comment: Whether you will be using the filter functionality for the `ArrayAdapter` is important to know and influences the correct answer.

Comment: @JaySoyer:No filter functionality used

Answer (score 2):

If you modify the list on the main/UI thread, then go ahead. The ListView itself operates also on the UI thread.

If you change the list from another thread, you may have to handle synchronization issues. Though it should not cause any problems when the ListView is not scrolling, i.e. does not access the Adapter.

To change the list anytime from another thread, you have to post all changes to the UI thread.

```
// this code is executed in another thread
// e.g. download some data
// determine which list elements get changed

// post to UI thread
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // change th actual list here and notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
});
```

If it's too complicated to determine what elements need to change, you also could create a new list and a new adapter:

```
// this code is executed in another thread
// e.g. download some data
// create a new list and/or a new adapter
final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(...);

// post to UI thread
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // set the new adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes I plan to update it via a background thread and then call the notify on the adapter. But I can not expect that the user will not be scrolling the list. So how should I implement this?

Comment: If the code that changes the ArrayList doesn't have much overhead then you could post that code to the UI thread, so it will be executed there.

Comment: I need to update the arraylist after fetching data from HTTP requests. So I can not do this in the UI thread

Comment: Is creating a new ArrayList or a new Adapter an option?

Comment: once you get the response, update the arraylist and call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: @Floern:Sure if that is the recommended approach

Comment: @Floern:But if I create a new arraylist how do I atomically replace the previous one?

Comment: @Floern:Wait my design target was to have the list item showning a spinner and then eventually replace it with the proper data. With your suggestion I don't think I can achieve that

Comment: @pvn:That does not seem to be thread safe if the adapter implementation does not copy the arraylist

Comment: @Jim you could try to create a new one and look whether it has unwanted side-effects. I updated my answer with some examples.

Comment: @Floern:Won't the `notifyDataSetChanged` cause the whole list to be re-rendered/processed?

Comment: @Jim yes, but you need to do that anyway if you change the list data, or else the new data will only be shown when the list scrolls.

Answer (score 1):

No, the UI is updated in the UI thread when you call notifyDataSetChanged(). Its handled by android properly

Comment: My question is if I I can/should modify the arraylist I pass to a custom array adapter from a background non-UI thread

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a custom adapter,what if you were to maintain 2 array lists.

```
public ArrayList<CustomObject> modifiableList;
private ArrayList<CustomObject> adapterList;
```

and you do all your changes to the modifiableList,

Then when you can determine the user is not scrolling your UI, you can call `notifyDatasetChangedCustom()`

**EDIT**: if you are doing it from another thread,you could maintain a WeakReference to your adapter and then call the changes.

```
 public notifyDatasetChangedCustom(){
    this.adapterList=this.modifiableList;
    this.notifyDatasetChanged();
 }
```

You could also try looking into [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html).This would take care addition of items and view updating automatically,although the implementation would be more complicated.

Comment: 1) `when you can determine the user is not scrolling your UI` how can I do this? 2) `this.adapterList=this.modifiableList;` is this atomic/thread safe?

Comment: It is possible yes, because the `modifiableList` is not used to update the listView.Based on your use case,I strongly suggest you look into Loaders.That would be perfect for your scenario.

Comment: To figure out if a user is scrolling:  Whenever you want to update,check if your scrollview has focus (isFocussed()) and then update if not focussed.