# Android ListView.getChildCount() greater than getCount()

Tags: android, listview

I have an `Activity` with a Fragment that displays a `ListView` containing simple `TextViews`.  A menu item can trigger another `Activity` via an Intent.  That new `Activity` clears the `ArrayList` underlying the `ArrayAdapter` for the `ListView` using `ArrayList.clear()`.

When I backup from the new `Activity` to my original one with the `ListView`, and get control in `onResume()`, I find that my `ListView.getChildCount()` is the same as when it was left due to the Intent, but the `ListView.getCount()` is now properly zero!

I have tried using the adapter's `clear()` method, I have tried `Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` (although I should not have to).

If I modify the underlying `ArrayList` from within the fragment itself, all seems fine.  For example, clicking on an element gives you an option to remove it, move it up or down, etc... That works OK.

Also, If I then leave the List `Activity` and return to it again, all is well.  So clearly the ArrayList is the same list.  I never create a new list, only .`clear()` it.

Any idea how the Child Count can possibly be more than the underlying element count?  Perhaps some kind of observer for the `ArrayList` does not trigger because the `Activity` is suspended?  In which case how could I sync them up again?  I have tried `invalidate()` for example.

This is under API 23.

Answer (score -1):

I seem to have found a workaround.  I noticed another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29742009/should-the-arraylist-passed-to-an-arrayadapter-of-a-list-be-thread-safe) discussing thread safety.  It seemed to have implications if you do not modify your list from the original UI.  So, in my onResume(), I just did a setAdapter() again.  With the same adapter and list, and viola!  All seems well again.